# Symmetric function on set of size four

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all nonempty subsets of $A$, and $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all subsets of $A$ of size $1$ or $2$.
>
> Is there a function $f:\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ such that for any $X,Y\in\mathcal{A}$: $f(X,Y)=f(Y,X)$, $f(X,Y)$ contains at least one element of $X$, and if $f(X,Y)$ contains exactly one element of $X$, then $f(X',Y)$ contains no more than one element of $X$ for any $X'\in\mathcal{A}$ ?

From the given conditions, if $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, $f(X,Y)$ contains exactly one element of both $X$ and $Y$. Moreover, we may deduce some values of $f$. For example assume that $f(12,3)=13$. (This is shorthand for $f(\{1,2\},\{3\})=\{1,3\})$. Then by the last condition, $f(12,13)=13$. Applying the last condition again, $f(2,13)=23$, which by the first condition means that $f(13,2)=23$. Similarly we can find the values of $f(1,23),f(12,23),f(13,23)$.

Comment: ...and why do you want to find such a function?

Comment: Because I think it's interesting...

Comment: No, I mean, how did you come up with this problem? Did it arise from some other problem you're trying to solve? Surely you didn't just ask yourself this out of the blue.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: It arises from a different problem, but this problem is interesting on its own as well.

Comment: why does $f(12,3)=13$ imply $f(12,13) = 13$?  couldn't $f(12,13)=1$ instead?  that doesnt seem to violate the 3rd rule.

Comment: If $f(12,13)=1$ then the 3rd rule (together with the 1st rule) implies that $f(12,X)$ cannot be $13$, for any $X$.

Comment: Why don't you program it? Enumerate all functions f, and for each check if it satisfies your desired conditions. Since the set is small, it should be fast to check.

Comment: Except it's not as small as you might think. There are $15\cdot 14/2$ values of $f$ to determine, and each can be one of $10$ values, which gives about $10^{20}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Not a full solution, but too long for a comment.** Since $f$ can be seen as a binary operator, from now on we will write it as $f(x,y)=x*y$. Your conditions can be rewritten as these.

1. $x*y=y*x$ (commutativity)
2. $x*y\cap x\neq\emptyset$
3. $|x*y\cap x|=1\implies|x'*y\cap x|\leq 1$

Suppose $x\neq y$, $|x|=|y|=1$ and $x,y\in\mathcal P(A)$. $|x*y\cap x|$ is at most $1$ since $|x|=1$, but due to property $2$, it is exactly $1$. Hence $x*y\cap x=x$ and $x\subseteq x*y$. Similarly $y\subseteq x*y$. Therefore $x\cup y\subseteq x*y$, but since $x*y\in\mathcal B$ whose elements are of size at most $2$, then $x*y=x\cup y=xy$ (we shall write this as a convenient shortform). Suppose that $|x|=1$ and $y=y_1y_2$ where $|y_1|=|y_2|=1$ (so $|y|=2$). Then $|x*y_1y_2\cap y_1y_2|\neq0$ implies that at least one of $y_1,y_2$ is in $x*y_1y_2$. Similarly, $x$ is in $x*y_1y_2$. So if $x$ and $y$ are disjoint, then $x*y$ has at least $2$ elements, so it has precisely $2$ elements (all items in $\mathcal B$ have size less than $3$). Thus exactly one of $y_1,y_2$ is in $x*y$. Similarly, if $x$ and $y_1y_2y_3$ are disjoint, then $x*y$ consists of $x$ and exactly one of $y_1,y_2,y_3$.